# Summing values based on a group by AS WELL as all of them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have at table with, say 10 columns. 8 columns of data and 2 columns (1 and 2) as an identifier.

I would like to calculate "the result" for the 8 columns, for every possible scenario of col1 and col2.

Assume distinct(value) col1 gives {A,B,C} and distinct(value) col2 gives {D,E,F} I would like to sum up the data (any of the 8 columns) GROUP'd BY:

- A,D
- A,E
- A,F
- A,(All of col2)
- B,D
- B,E
- B,F
- B,(All of col2)
- C,D
- C,E
- C,F
- C,(All of col2)
- (All of col1),(All of col2)
- D, (All of col1)
- E, (All of col1)
- F, (All of col1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(colx) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1)       AS [All of col1],
    SUM(colx) OVER (PARTITION BY Col2)       AS [All of col2],
    SUM(colx) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2) AS [PerCol1Col2Pair],
    SUM(colx) OVER ()                        AS [All of col1 and All of col2]
FROM
    MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want `GROUP BY CUBE()` (see [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)):

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM atable
GROUP BY CUBE(col1, col2)
```

This'll produce results like below:

```
col1  col2  cnt
----  ----  --------
A     D     xAD
A     E     xAE
A     …     …
B     D     xBD
B     E     xBE
B     …     …
A     NULL  xAD + xAE + …
B     NULL  xBD + xBE + …
NULL  D     xAD + xBD + …
NULL  E     xAE + xBE + …
…     …     …
NULL  NULL  xAD + xAE + … + xBD + xBE + …
```